# How to read structures from a file into an array, modify it and write it back?

Tags: c, struct

I hope the title is correct, i cant describe it better, sorry. I have a struct with pointers thats propagated during the "session" of a program. Of course, this structure is thrown everytime so i want to save the current state to a binary file. Because entry:data is a pointer to an array of unknown length, i tried to append the length to each entry. So far everything is working fine, but when i want to delete or append an antry i run into problems. I want to create an array of (struct entry) with the length thats in the file header but as soon as i create the struct the function doesnt work anymore.

Here is a minimal working example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct header {
    int id;
    int len;
};

struct entry {
    int id;       
    int len; // length of data        
    char *data;   
};

void createNewStorage() {

    FILE *f = fopen("test.bin", "wb");   

    // create a header with id=1 and len=2 
    struct header hdr = {1, 2};
    fwrite(&hdr, sizeof(struct header), 1, f);

    char *data;

    data = "This is some data of unknown length, i hope it works";
    int id = 1;
    int len = strlen(data);    
    struct entry e = {id, len, data};
    fwrite(&e.id, sizeof(int), 1, f);
    fwrite(&e.len, sizeof(int), 1, f);
    fwrite(e.data, sizeof(char), strlen(e.data), f);

    id = 2; 
    data = "\x01\x12\x23"; 
    len = strlen(data); 
    e.id = id;
    e.data = data;
    e.len = len;
    fwrite(&e.id, sizeof(int), 1, f);
    fwrite(&e.len, sizeof(int), 1, f);
    fwrite(e.data, sizeof(char), e.len, f);

    fclose(f);

}

void appendNewEntry() {

    FILE *f = fopen("test.bin", "rb");       

    // get the header
    struct header hdr;
    fread(&hdr.id, sizeof(int), 1, f);
    fread(&hdr.len, sizeof(int), 1, f);
    printf("hdr: id='%d', len='%d'\n", hdr.id, hdr.len);

    // get the entries
    int id, len = 0; char *data; 
    int i = 0;
    while(i < hdr.len) {    
        fread(&id, sizeof(int), 1, f);
        fread(&len, sizeof(int), 1, f);
        fread(&data, sizeof(char), len, f);
        printf("entry: id='%d', len='%d', data='%s'\n", id, len, &data);
        i++;        
    }    
    printf("Done..\n");
    fclose(f);

}

int main(void){
    createNewStorage();
    appendNewEntry();
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you in advance.

**Edit**: Finally i got it working, here is the final code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct header {
    int id;
    int len;
};

struct entry {
    int id;       
    int len; // length of data        
    char *data;   
};

void create() {
    FILE *f = fopen("test.bin", "wb");   
    // create a header with id=1 and len=2 
    struct header hdr = {1, 2};
    fwrite(&hdr, sizeof(struct header), 1, f);
    char *data;
    data = "This is some data of unknown length, i hope it works";
    int id = 1;
    int len = strlen(data);    
    struct entry e = {id, len, data};
    fwrite(&e.id, sizeof(int), 1, f);
    fwrite(&e.len, sizeof(int), 1, f);
    fwrite(e.data, sizeof(char), strlen(e.data), f);
    id = 2; 
    data = "\x01\x12\x23"; 
    len = strlen(data); 
    e.id = id;
    e.data = data;
    e.len = len;
    fwrite(&e.id, sizeof(int), 1, f);
    fwrite(&e.len, sizeof(int), 1, f);
    fwrite(e.data, sizeof(char), e.len, f);
    fclose(f);
}

void modify() {
    FILE *f = fopen("test.bin", "rb");       
    // get the header
    struct header hdr;
    fread(&hdr.id, sizeof(int), 1, f);
    fread(&hdr.len, sizeof(int), 1, f);
    printf("Reading storage hdr: id='%d', len='%d' ", hdr.id, hdr.len);
    // create a new list to store all existing entries
    struct entry list[hdr.len];    
    // get the entries
    int id, len = 0; char *data; 
    int i = 0;
    while(i < hdr.len) {    
        fread(&id, sizeof(int), 1, f);
        fread(&len, sizeof(int), 1, f);
        data = malloc((len + 1) * sizeof(char));
        fread(data, sizeof(char), len, f);
        data[len] = '\0';
        //printf("entry: id='%d', len='%d', data='%s'\n", id, len, &data[0]);
        struct entry e = {id, len, data};
        list[i] = e;
        i++;        
    }    
    printf("Done..\n");
    printf("The list has %d entries\n", i);
    int il = 0;
    while(il < i) {
        printf("entry %d: len='%d', data='%s'\n", il, list[il].len, list[il].data);
        il++;
    }    
    fclose(f);
}

void append(char *newdata) {
    printf("Appending new data..\n");
    FILE *f = fopen("test.bin", "rb");       
    // get the header
    struct header hdr;
    fread(&hdr.id, sizeof(int), 1, f);
    fread(&hdr.len, sizeof(int), 1, f);
    printf("Reading storage hdr: id='%d', len='%d' ", hdr.id, hdr.len);
    // create a new list to store all existing entries
    struct entry list[hdr.len];    
    // get the entries
    int id, len = 0; char *data; 
    int i = 0;
    while(i < hdr.len) {    
        fread(&id, sizeof(int), 1, f);
        fread(&len, sizeof(int), 1, f);
        data = malloc((len + 1) * sizeof(char));
        fread(data, sizeof(char), len, f);
        data[len] = '\0';
        //printf("entry: id='%d', len='%d', data='%s'\n", id, len, &data[0]);
        struct entry e = {id, len, data};
        list[i] = e;
        i++;        
    }    
    printf("Done..\n");
    /*
    printf("The list has %d entries\n", i);
    int il = 0;
    while(il < i) {
        printf("entry %d: len='%d', data='%s'\n", il, list[il].len, list[il].data);
        il++;
    }
    */
    fclose(f);    
    f = fopen("test.bin", "wb");    
    struct header outhdr = {hdr.id, hdr.len+1};
    fwrite(&outhdr, sizeof(struct header), 1, f);    
    int il = 0;
    while(il < i) {
        printf("writing entry %d\n", il, list[il].len, list[il].data);
        fwrite(&list[il].id, sizeof(int), 1, f);
        fwrite(&list[il].len, sizeof(int), 1, f);
        fwrite(&list[il].data[0], sizeof(char), list[il].len, f);
        il++;
    }
    il++;
    struct entry e;
    int nid = il;  
    int nlen = strlen(newdata); 
    e.id = nid;
    e.data = newdata;
    e.len = nlen;
    printf("writing new entry\n");
    fwrite(&e.id, sizeof(int), 1, f);
    fwrite(&e.len, sizeof(int), 1, f);
    fwrite(e.data, sizeof(char), e.len, f);        
    fclose(f);    
}

void erase(int entryId) {
    printf("Appending new data..\n");
    FILE *f = fopen("test.bin", "rb");       
    // get the header
    struct header hdr;
    fread(&hdr.id, sizeof(int), 1, f);
    fread(&hdr.len, sizeof(int), 1, f);
    printf("Reading storage hdr: id='%d', len='%d' ", hdr.id, hdr.len);
    // create a new list to store all existing entries
    struct entry list[hdr.len];    
    // get the entries
    int id, len = 0; char *data; 
    int i = 0;
    while(i < hdr.len) {    
        fread(&id, sizeof(int), 1, f);
        fread(&len, sizeof(int), 1, f);
        data = malloc((len + 1) * sizeof(char));
        fread(data, sizeof(char), len, f);
        data[len] = '\0';
        //printf("entry: id='%d', len='%d', data='%s'\n", id, len, &data[0]);
        struct entry e = {id, len, data};
        list[i] = e;
        i++;        
    }    
    printf("Done..\n");
    /*
    printf("The list has %d entries\n", i);
    int il = 0;
    while(il < i) {
        printf("entry %d: len='%d', data='%s'\n", il, list[il].len, list[il].data);
        il++;
    }
    */
    fclose(f);
    f = fopen("test.bin", "wb");    
    struct header outhdr = {hdr.id, hdr.len-1};
    fwrite(&outhdr, sizeof(struct header), 1, f);    
    int il = 0;
    while(il < i) {
        if(list[il].id == entryId) {
            // this is the one to delete
            //printf("THIS IS IT -> %d\n", il);
        } else {
            printf("writing entry %d\n", il, list[il].len, list[il].data);
            fwrite(&list[il].id, sizeof(int), 1, f);
            fwrite(&list[il].len, sizeof(int), 1, f);
            fwrite(&list[il].data[0], sizeof(char), list[il].len, f);
        }
        il++;
    }       
}

int main(void){

    create();

    getch();

    char *input;
    input = "Mein Hund ist der aller aller Beste";
    append(input);

    getch();

    erase(1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you please describe in more detail what "doesnt work" means for your program? What is the expected result and actual result?

Comment: 'doesnt work' menas it just stops. have you tried to reproduce it? does it work for you? on my computer the curser icon pops up the loading cursor and then the console crashes. There is nothing more i can say, really.

Comment: You haven't provided a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which makes it hard to try. Please do so.

Comment: Ii will provide it in a minute..

Comment: Run it in a debugger and it can point you immediately to the problem: `fread(&data[0], sizeof(char), len, f);` it barfs on that line. Does that give you any clues?

Comment: Or turn up compiler warnings with `-Wall`. It will give: `warning: ‘data’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]`.

Comment: Sorry it doesnt give me any clue, just that i am not as good as you. I've never used a debugger, otherwise i wont ask, i guess :P Sorry can you lead me a bit? How do i initialize it correctly? I have created a pointer outside of the loop, isnt that an initialization?

Comment: Before going any further, compile your code with `gcc -Wall -Werror -o program program.c` where you replace `program` with your actual file name. This will display most warnings and treat warnings as errors. That is to say, you won't be able to run the code until you fix the code causing the warnings.

Comment: You created a pointer but it doesn't point anywhere. That is, there is no memory buffer for your data to be written to. The example code doesn't make it clear what you want to do with the data so it is hard to tell you exactly what you want to do. I'm guessing you'll want to allocate some dynamic memory for the data. Something like `data = malloc(len+1); fread(data, sizeof(char), len, f);`

Comment: Ok, i changed "&data" to "&data[0]", compile it as you say and get no warnings at all! But it dont work. So whats this now?

Comment: Getting rid of the warnings is necessary but not sufficient. You need to understand what the warning means and resole it correctly and not just do something to get rid of it for the sake of it.

Comment: I wrote all this stuff in my question, i want to append/delete an entry and save the new list back! As simple as that!

Comment: Ok david cullen i wont get it, never mind..

Comment: @phpnoob As you discovered, silencing warnings is not equivalent to fixing the problem. I went to the trouble of creating a complete answer below where I do my best to fix the immediate problems and generate what I hope is the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct header {
    int id;
    int len;
};

struct entry {
    int id;
    int len; // length of data
    char *data;
};

void createNewStorage() {

    FILE *f = fopen("test.bin", "wb");

    // create a header with id=1 and len=2
    struct header hdr = {1, 2};
    fwrite(&hdr, sizeof(struct header), 1, f);

    char *data;

    data = "This is some data of unknown length, i hope it works";
    int id = 1;
    int len = strlen(data);
    struct entry e = {id, len, data};
    fwrite(&e.id, sizeof(int), 1, f);
    fwrite(&e.len, sizeof(int), 1, f);
    fwrite(e.data, sizeof(char), strlen(e.data), f);

    id = 2;
    data = "\x01\x12\x23";
    len = strlen(data);
    e.id = id;
    e.data = data;
    e.len = len;
    fwrite(&e.id, sizeof(int), 1, f);
    fwrite(&e.len, sizeof(int), 1, f);
    fwrite(e.data, sizeof(char), e.len, f);

    fclose(f);

}

void appendNewEntry() {

    FILE *f = fopen("test.bin", "rb");

    // get the header
    struct header hdr;
    fread(&hdr.id, sizeof(int), 1, f);
    fread(&hdr.len, sizeof(int), 1, f);
    printf("hdr: id='%d', len='%d'\n", hdr.id, hdr.len);

    // get the entries
    int id, len = 0; char *data;
    int i = 0;
    while(i < hdr.len) {
        fread(&id, sizeof(int), 1, f);
        fread(&len, sizeof(int), 1, f);
        data = malloc((len + 1) * sizeof(char));
        fread(data, sizeof(char), len, f);
        data[len] = '\0';
        printf("entry: id='%d', len='%d', data='%s'\n", id, len, data);
        i++;
    }
    printf("Done..\n");
    fclose(f);

}

int main(void){
    createNewStorage();
    appendNewEntry();
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
hdr: id='1', len='2'
entry: id='1', len='52', data='This is some data of unknown length, i hope it works'
entry: id='2', len='3', data='#'
Done..
```

**Note**

I had to add `#inlude <stdlib.h>` to use `malloc`. The original code was using `&data` in `fread` and `printf` unnecessarily. Also, it does not look like the data is actually read into a list of `entry`, which seems odd.

**Warning**

This code allocates memory and it is the users responsibility to free the memory before the program ends.

Comment: Before going any further, compile your code with gcc -Wall -Werror. Any errors? Try to replace "&data" with "&data[0]".

Comment: @phpnoob I have a version of your code that runs and prints out the data. Have a look.

Comment: Nice, thank you very much! Sorry for my inpatience. Its getting harder and harder to ask on SO. I have edited my question, see my final code including append and delete functions. ps: i hope you know my 1st comment was a bad joke :P